# AssertJ: Retrieving First Items From Extracting List Returns List Instead

Tags: java, assertj

I'm trying to verify first item in an extracted List. However AssertJ returns a `List` instead of expected object from `.first()`.

Given the following sample

```
public class AssertJTests
{
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Region Asia should only have one Country, Malaysia")
    public void assertRegion()
    {
        Region asia = new Region()
            .setName("Asia")
            .setCountries(Lists.newArrayList("Malaysia"));

        Consumer<Region> regionRequirement = region ->
            assertThat(region)
                .extracting(Region::getName)
                .containsOnly("Asia");

        Consumer<String> countryRequirement = country ->
            assertThat(country)
                .isEqualToIgnoringCase("Malaysia");

        assertThat(asia)
            .isInstanceOfSatisfying(Region.class, regionRequirement)
            .extracting(Region::getCountries)
            .hasSize(1)
            .first()
            .isInstanceOfSatisfying(String.class, countryRequirement);
}

    protected static class Region
    {
        private String name;

        private List<String> countries;

        List<String> getCountries()
        {
            return countries;
        }

        Region setCountries(final List<String> pCountries)
        {
            countries = pCountries;
            return this;
         }

         String getName()
         {
            return name;
         }

         Region setName(final String pName)
         {
             name = pName;
             return this;
          }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting `.first()` to return `String` but instead it returned `List<String>`. The following error appeared:

> java.lang.AssertionError: [List check first element] 
> Expecting:
>   <["Malaysia"]>
> to be an instance of:
>   <java.lang.String>
> but was instance of:
>   <java.util.ArrayList>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`extracting`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting-java.util.function.Function...-) for `Object` assertion extracts the object under test (here `asia`) properties resulting in a `List` of extracted property values. Your code results in extracting only one property so the result is a list of one value, it turns out that the value is also a list, after `extracting` you end up having is a `List` of one element being `asia.countries`.

Comment: Ideally the API could provide `extracting(Function singleExtractor)`  that would return the value directly (if adding this does not lead to a conflict resolution with `extracting(Function... extractors)`.

Comment: I understand that extracting `countries` returns a list but I'm unclear on why does `.first()` returns a list as well while `countries` is `List<String>` instead of `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I finally got it after re-read your feedback. Do ignore my comment above.

Comment: Well the fact that you had to re-read my comment is a clear indication that the API should provide `extracting(Function singleExtractor)`, I have created https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1246 for this.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like they fixed the problem because the following works now:

```
assertThat(asia)
  .extracting(Region::getCountries)
  .asList()
  .first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assert using the `contains` and `extracting` method of API.

For Example:

```
@Test
public void oneDateShouldNotAfterAnotherDate() {
    
    Set<String> errors = ...;

    Assertions
            .assertThat(errors)
            .isNotEmpty()   
            .contains("OneDate_ShouldNot_After_AnotherDate");
    
    /*
        If you need assert specific field of object. Then:
     */
    Set<Error> errors = ...;

    Assertions
            .assertThat(errors)
            .isNotEmpty()
            .extracting("message")
            .contains("OneDate_ShouldNot_After_AnotherDate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few years late to the party but

```
.flatExtracting("countries")
```

should probably work for you